# PayPal Rest API - Webhooks / IPN - Is it possible to receive eBay payment notifications?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been developing a marketplace type platform. Implementing PayPal Payouts seemed to be perfect for dealing with commissions. Especially being as PayPal will be handling all payments too.

I've successfully developed this part of the system. Inc. the webhook and verifying transmissions.

Now I wish to get my eBay sales info into my system. So that we can see it all in one place and have the system work the commissions out for those sales too. Having just invested the time into learning and implementing this PayPal API integration, it would be nice to use it for getting this data too.

So having tested the sandbox app thoroughly for the Payouts, I configured the live one. This is in my PayPal developer account where the app settings are. I've done nothing in my main Paypal account. Am I meant too?

My live webhook URL is just set to log all received data from PayPal. So I waited for a eBay sale and went to check the log but no data received? Am I misunderstanding this? The webhook is subscribed to all events.

The Drupal Commerce shopping cart I'm using already implements a IPN. Is it the IPN that I need to be thinking about? I'd prefer to not interfere with it to be honest, to keep future security updates safer. That said, I suspect there will be a way to extend it.

I guess the **actual question is** - what is the easiest way to get eBay sales info through PayPal?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eBay has their own system for that called [Platform Notifications](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Notifications/Notifications.html).

If I'm working with payment data, and I just need extra data from eBay, I will typically start with PayPal IPN / Webhooks and then use the eBay APIs within my IPN app to pull and push data as necessary.

Of course, depending on the scenario, you may decide to build out your primary solution inside of an eBay Platform Notifications app, and then make calls to PayPal APIs within that if you need to pull/push data.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I was trying to avoid eBay integration by using PayPal. However my research has been pointing to the same thing. I found that the IPN from paypal didn't contain my custom SKU. Leaving me unable to use it as I wanted